# Reformating CSS file

Tags: css, formatting

I want to borrow some of SO's CSS file and modify it, but I see the CSS is packed into very unreadable format. How can I reformat to a well formed readable CSS file?

Comment: maybe with a good text editor like textmate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view and copy the CSS using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com)'s CSS Panel.

[image: Firebug CSS Panel]

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this using a text editor

- replace every ';' with ';\n'
- replace every  '}' with '}\n'

Answer (score 1):

This site has a very nice tool built into the page to unminify/beautify CSS.  You can even set the width of tabs.

http://mrcoles.com/blog/css-unminify/